# Secure asp.net core 2.0 webapi with Identityserver3

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver3, asp.net-core-webapi

I am completely new to Identityserver and authorization.

There is an authorization server build using Identityserver3. It works fine with asp.net mvc 5 application.

Now i am trying to use this authorization server to secure the new asp.net core 2.0 webapi.

I couldn't find any good document about how to do this. Can anyone help how to do achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The same way as you will do it if you use IdentityServer 4. In your .NET Core 2.0 Web API, in the `Startup.cs` :

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "<identityserverurl>";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ApiName = "mynetcoreapi";
            });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

and of course you need `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` package, but it is a .NET Core package, so you shouldn't have any problems.

PS: Don't forget to setup logging (if it is not already done) in your IdentityServer. Helps a lot